# NO shaded jar found in target after maven shade plugin packages the project

Tags: java, maven-shade-plugin

On running `mvn package:shade shade`, the log has entry which says:**Replacing XYZ.jar with XYZ-shaded.jar**
but in my target directory, I cannot find shaded jar
[image]

This is my pom regarding maven shade

[image]

After trying , this pom helped me

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Main-Class>akkaexample.Akkmain</Main-Class>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>akkaexample.Akkmain</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have your checked whether the output jar file is the shaded one?

The Shade plugin is probably *replacing* the original file here, meaning overwriting it with the shaded version.

If you wish to get both jar files (shaded and unshaded) at the end, you probably need to set the `shadedArtifactAttached` property to `true`:

> Defines whether the shaded artifact should be attached as classifier to the original artifact. If false, the shaded jar will be the main artifact of the project

See [Maven Shade Mojo Documentation.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html)

Comment: @RomaJain Ok. Can you perhaps add the section of the pom regarding the shade plugin to the question?

Comment: Interesting, this works for me on my OSX, but my windows compadres didn't have to do this.